# How to find out, what python process\code does so much time (this happens ~ once a month and already works 92 hours)?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with uWSGI which runs everyday job:

`cron2 = minute=00,hour=1,unique=1 ./manage.py catalogue_create db --update_all_indexes=True`

In my case `catalogue_create db` downloads json file and updates products' prices, indexes and other things. Usually it takes about 1 hour.

Sometimes (about once a month or even once a two months) the process can not be finished.

In `htop` (I use Ubuntu Server) I see the next:

`PID USER PRI NI VIRT RES SHR S CPU% MEM%      TIME+
                                 31  46.6%    92h22:46`

Usualy I simply reboot the server but this time I want to find out, how is it possible to see, what this process (or the script) does? Why does it take so long and can not be finished.

Comment: edit your answer and show us `manage.py`. Can't see the problem being in the specification of your cron job.... What is your db doing during these events?

Comment: As a first step you should add (more) logging to your code.

Comment: @ShawnMehan, manage.py is standard and not edited. Colud you tell how to check what my db is doing? Can not find any article in inet.

Comment: @KlausD. I thought about this way, but decided to ask... Maybe there is any other way... because catalogue_create.py has a lot of code... Log file can become very huge since server restart until I face a problem again.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler

Comment: You are showing some `top` info on your python process. Surely your db has a similar line in the top? You have to be able to isolate your code and debug or you are really not in control. Build a second db and work on that until you can replicate the event....